# Appliaciont hosted in IIS is accesible with the host name from some machines but not in others

Tags: iis-7.5, deployment

I hosted an application under default website in IIS. the application is **windows authenticated intranet Application.** When I try to access the application outside the hosted server. I am able to access it with the host name from some machines. while the other machines throw error message "The resource cannot be found". in these machines(where i get the error) if i try to access with the IP address instead of host name i am able to access the site.

my host server name is kdev

i try to Access the application as http:\kdev\usersetupapp\home.aspx 
This works fine in some machines. but not in other system
I am able to access the application with the IP adress as shown below

http://[10.0.0.1]/usersetupapp/home.aspx

Please help me resolving the issue

Also please let me know if it is fine to host an intranet application under default  website itself, or do I need to host it as  a separate website. Also If i have to host as separate website do i need to ad DNS entry for the host name?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a name resolution problem with the clients that cannot access the application. Based on the URL you're trying to use you need to be able to execute `ping kdev` on a client and see the name resolve to the server's IP address. Until that works a browser isn't going to work either.

I have a suspicion that you're getting broadcast name resolution for machines that are on-subnet with the IIS server, which would explain how you're able to access the server from some clients but not others.

You should create an "A" record in domain the clients are using for their fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) to map "kdev" to the proper IP address.

w/ respect to the "Default Web Site" - It's just something that's created during IIS installation. It has no relationship to DNS, per se, and you're fine to install applications into it if you prefer. If you decide to make other web sites *and* you opt to use HTTP host headers to identify them then you will need DNS records corresponding to the host header names if you intend clients to be able to resolve the web site names and access the sites (which, I'd think, you'd want).

It sounds like you would benefit from reading-up on how DNS and HTTP host headers work.